# Removing non-integer entries from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this one:

```
array( [0] => 1
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 3
       [3] => Some strings
)
```

How can I remove an entry that is not an integer number from an array? I need to output this:

```
array( [0] => 1
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 3
)
```

Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, 'is_int');
```

#### Edit:

As noted in the comments, it may be a better solution to use one of the following instead.

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');
$filtered = array_filter($array, 'ctype_digit');
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know array_filter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The array_filter detects all the entries as strings. How can I convert the integer entries in integers?

Comment: You could have a look at [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead of `is_int`

Comment: Solved using: $filtered = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');

Comment: [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) might be more suitable than is_numeric

Comment: @goat the only issue is that the actual type of the value has to be a `string` for  `ctype_digit` to work, if it's an `int` it will fail

Answer (score 3):

If you are consuming the input from `$_POST` or `$_GET`, then there is a problem with each of the following.

- `array_filter($array, 'is_numeric')` will also accept fractional values eg. `2.5`
- `array_filter($array, 'is_int');` will reject most `int` inputs as the values posted over `$_GET` or `$_POST` are considered as strings even if they contain valid `integers`.
- `array_filter($array, 'ctype_digit');` will reject inputs if they contain valid `integers` as it only matches integers that are represented as a string.

So the safest approach to filter an array for only valid Integers, is

```
array_filter($ids, function($e){ return ctype_digit( (string) $e );})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) and [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sanitising for a database, try

```
$int_array = array_map('intval', $array);
```

Everything will be sanitised as an integer, however bad conversions will be 0