# How can I filter the number and delete string on array and return new one?

Tags: php

I have an array. for example :

```
$arr = [ 1 , 'a' , 'b', 2];
```

I want to return a new array:

```
$arr [ 1 , 2 ];
```

I trued to use `is_numeric` and `unsed` but it didn't work for me. I hope you can tell me the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please share your effort? Doesn't matter that it didn't work, if you post the code you tried, we can point out where exactly you went wrong and then you can learn more than by just receiving a working solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing non-integer entries from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639192/removing-non-integer-entries-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this use function is_numeric in array_filter

```
$a1=array(1,3,2,3,4,'a','d');
print_r(array_filter($a1,"is_numeric"));
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **array_filter** function to do that.

here is how you can do it:

```
 $result = array_filter($arr,function($k){
      return gettype($k) != 'string';
    });
```